# Insurance deductable problem

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose the random variable $X$ represents the amount of damage done to a rusty Pontiac Sunfire during the 2007-2007 year. Ninety-two percent of the time, the vehicle will sustain no damage. Otherwise we model the damage to be uniformly distributed on the interval [500,3000].

If the insurance were purchased with a $1000$ deductible, calculate the average insurance payment.

My thinking was this, there is a $.08$ chance that damage will occur so that means $Y=.08X$. But $X=\dfrac{1}{2500} \;\text{if}\; 500\leq x\leq 3000$. So the expected amount should be:

$0.08\cdot \bigg[\displaystyle\int_{500}^{3000}\dfrac{x}{2500} - \displaystyle\int_{500}^{1000}\dfrac{x}{2500}\bigg]$ but this isn't the answer. Whats wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insurance company payout is $0$ if damage is from $0$ to $1000$, and $X-1000$ if $1000\le X\le 2000$.

The probability of a payout is $(0.08)\frac{3000-1000}{2500}$.
Thus with probability $0.064$ there is a payout $Y$, uniformly distributed between $0$ and $2000$. It follows that 
$$E(Y)=(0.064)\int_{0}^{2000}\frac{y}{2000}\,dy.$$

**Remark:** The calculation in the OP does not take account of the fact that if, for example, the damage is $1400$, then the insurance company only pays out $400$.

Comment: They get 100 vs the 64 im getting here

Comment: I know what I did wrong I forgot to account for the fact that I'm subtracting 1000 from $x$ in my integral changing it to $.08\int_{1000}^{3000} \dfrac{x-1000}{2500}$ but I still get 64

Comment: Well, then we agree.

Comment: so book is wrong again heh

Comment: I just figured out how they get the 100. Seems they just did $\dfrac{3000-500}{2} \cdot .08 = 100$ They just subtract 500 to account for the 500 lost. Now I'm a bit confused because this actually makes some sense in a way. But do they account for the fact that they have a deductible of 1000?